# Default font size of JavaFX under Linux is larger as on Windows

Tags: linux, windows, fonts, javafx, size

I noticed that the default font is way larger in JavaFX under Linux (Ubuntu XY) as it is under Windows. Since screen space is sometimes quite limited i would like to have it ideally the same size as it is under Windows. Is there a simple way to enforce the same default size / the same DPI value?

Answer (score 2):

In short, font rendering will depend of the OS. So you will have more/less pixels for the same word depending of the OS where java is running. One good practice is to use: USE_COMPUTED_SIZE as much as possible to avoid problems and let your app just fit by it self depending on the size of the fonts.

Check this guide to know how java works with fonts:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/intl/fontconfig.html

This is not 100% related to your question but just check these comparisons (Windows,Linux,Mac):
http://fxexperience.com/2013/01/modena-new-theme-for-javafx-8/

Comment: To clarify my question - the reason for the question:

Everything looks not really sharp. Since the font is bigger everything scales up (normally desired). But ironically the borders, which would be 1px wide, are now 1.33px width and so on. This means that everything is blurry. The reason is that some values of the default theme are set in 'em' instead of 'px'. So i hoped to adjust the font size in a way that it's get bach to the 1px values.