# JavaFX Windows Design differs on Linux

Tags: java, javafx

I build the following JavaFX-Application on Windows.
On Linux the button size and font size does not match.
Label, Textfield und Button descriptons do not fit to its dimension.

[image: Picture 1]
[image]

**How can I set the font size of my program so that it looks like under windows?**

Changing the font size and font style manually does not works very well as it does not fit the dimension. Or maybe I did not find the right combination.

Thanks in Advance

Windows and Linux using JDK 8.
- Tool for JavaFX: SceneBuilder by Gluon

The following does not help:
[Default font size of JavaFX under Linux is larger as on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28350260/default-font-size-of-javafx-under-linux-is-larger-as-on-windows)
[Modena – new theme for JavaFX 8](http://fxexperience.com/2013/01/modena-new-theme-for-javafx-8/)

Comment: You might want to check your own Linux desktop environment settings. For example, most Linux DEs have their own settings for font sizes. These can override anything you code in JavaFX.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using Lubuntu. Sadly I can not see any environment settings changing the font size. Link two shows that on Ubuntu the font size is an other size than on windows. I do not know why Java is doing that as it makes no sense.

Comment: Much of how applications are displayed depends on the operating system. I still believe there is something going on with Xfce (I believe Lubuntu still uses that?) and its Window Manager.  One thing I would suggest as a workaround if you can't figure this out, is to set the `minWidth` properties for your containers to match the `prefWidth` value. That way, the containers will always expand to hold show its children in full.

Comment: Check Google for how you can confirm the DPI settings in Lubuntu. If it's anything over 100%, the visual elements will all be enlarged in Linux; that has nothing to do with Java (you could see the same effect in Windows by increasing the DPI value).

Comment: 1) ~/.Xresources
 Xft.dpi: 96

2) gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor 1
3) gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 1.0
4) gsettings set com.ubuntu.user-interface scale-factor "{'HDMI1': 8, 'eDP1': 8}"

did all not help.

First one work well for many applications but not for JavaFX.
Some people think it would be fixed in Java 9.

Comment: Java Oracle 10.0.2 does also not work.

Comment: Here also no good solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28937392/javafx-alerts-and-their-size?rq=1

Comment: Probably just bad use of layout nodes.

Comment: I do not need any resizing, but it is really hard if the os displays the text in different font sizes. Everything in a fixed size would be totally sufficient.

Comment: Well, you should always account for the user having different settings when designing anyway. So while you may have found a bug, designing your interface to allow larger fonts (as my prior comment suggested) is still going to be a good idea. You can't always control what the end user is going to do.

Comment: On a side note, do NOT erase all data if the wrong password is entered! Lol what an easy way for a bad guy to do some damage :-P

Comment: Create a sample app that demos your  problem.

Comment: Relying on such minute differences is usually a sign of problematic design - some people have trouble reading small fonts and will have larger font sizes defined, there is no way around it. 
On a more practical note - the difference in sizes is probably due to different fonts used - assuming you left all fonts as the default `System` - the default system font will be used, which is different between Linux and Windows, and even between different versions of Windows or Linux distros. The only way around it is to explicitly specify a font and include it in your program.

Answer (score 1):

*[EDIT: It occurs to me that I came up with this "solution" before having much awareness of themes. Next time I'm dealing with this, I will check if the explicitly making the theme on both Windows and Mac/Linux identical (rather than allowing their respective defaults) eliminates this problem.]*

I was pretty disappointed to find out that the famous "write once--run everywhere" program had this rather significant shortfall. I'm holding out the hope that there is a more elegant way to deal with it, or something I'm missing or misunderstanding, but for now am going in and specifying sizings for the given OS. From what I've seen, there are only two operating system scaling sizes that need to be accommodated: Windows on one hand and Linux/Mac on the other.

If there's only one or two sizes to tweak, something like the following can work:

```
    String os = System.getProperty("os.name","generic").toLowerCase(Locale.US);
    if (os.indexOf("mac") > 0) {
        root.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 14pt");           
    }
```

In this case, the Windows default font had a size of 10pt and my Mac user wanted something larger, and the program was not otherwise being widely distributed. Once the style is set for the group at the base of the scene graph (I usually name it 'root'), it will pertain to the entire graph unless over ridden.

But for more elaborate situations, I've used something like the following static class. When I distribute the application, which is usually as a self-contained program (using JLINK), the OS is known and can be set at the top of the file. I might as well just post the whole class. You will probably have different specifics, and more or fewer things that need tweaking.

If there are better ways to handle this, and I am all ears.

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Insets;

/**
 * This file contains values needed that pertain to the
 * difference in the size relationships of fonts:pixels in
 * Mac OS and Windows. 
 * 
 * @author Phil Freihofner
 */
public class OSConstants {

    public enum OS {WIN, MAC_LINUX};
    public static OS os;
    {
//      os = OS.WIN;
        os = OS.MAC_LINUX;
    }
    
    public static Font tinySizeFont;
    public static Font smallSizeFont;
    public static Font normalSizeFont;
    public static Font largeSizeFont;
    public static Font bigLabelFont;
    public static Font cboChoicesFont;
    public static Font buttonFont;
    public static int preferenceButtonSpacer;
        
    public static Insets gridButtonInsets;
    public static Insets gridCBOInsets;
    public static Insets gridLabelInsets;
    public static Insets gridRadioInsets;
    public static Insets gridSliderInsets;
    
    private final int MAC_TINY_FONT_SIZE = 7;
    private final int MAC_SMALL_FONT_SIZE = 8;
    private final int MAC_CBO_FONT_SIZE = 10;
    private final int MAC_NORMAL_FONT_SIZE = 11;
    private final int MAC_LARGE_FONT_SIZE = 15;
    private final int MAC_BIG_LABEL_FONT_SIZE = 20;
    private final int MAC_PREFERENCE_BUTTON_SPACER = -16;

    private final Insets MAC_GRID_BUTTON_INSETS = new Insets(-1, -1, -1, -1);
    private final Insets MAC_GRID_CBO_INSETS = new Insets(-1, -1, -1, -2);
    private final Insets MAC_GRID_LABEL_INSETS = new Insets(-1, -1, -1, -1);
    private final Insets MAC_GRID_RADIO_INSETS = new Insets(-1, -1, -1, -1);
    private final Insets MAC_GRID_SLIDER_INSETS = new Insets(-1, -1, -1, -1);
    
    private final int WIN_TINY_FONT_SIZE = 8;
    private final int WIN_SMALL_FONT_SIZE = 9;
    private final int WIN_CBO_FONT_SIZE = 11;
    private final int WIN_NORMAL_FONT_SIZE = 12;
    private final int WIN_LARGE_FONT_SIZE = 16;
    private final int WIN_BIG_LABEL_FONT_SIZE = 24;
    private final int WIN_PREFERENCE_BUTTON_SPACER = -22;
    
    private final Insets WIN_GRID_BUTTON_INSETS = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
    private final Insets WIN_GRID_CBO_INSETS = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
    private final Insets WIN_GRID_LABEL_INSETS = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
    private final Insets WIN_GRID_RADIO_INSETS = new Insets(2, 10, 2, 2);
    private final Insets WIN_GRID_SLIDER_INSETS = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
    
    OSConstants()
    {
        if (os == OS.WIN)
        {
            tinySizeFont = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.PLAIN, WIN_TINY_FONT_SIZE);
            smallSizeFont = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.PLAIN, WIN_SMALL_FONT_SIZE);
            normalSizeFont = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, WIN_NORMAL_FONT_SIZE);
            largeSizeFont = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, WIN_LARGE_FONT_SIZE);
            bigLabelFont = new Font(Font.SERIF, Font.BOLD, WIN_BIG_LABEL_FONT_SIZE);
            cboChoicesFont = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, WIN_CBO_FONT_SIZE);
            buttonFont = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, WIN_NORMAL_FONT_SIZE);
            preferenceButtonSpacer = WIN_PREFERENCE_BUTTON_SPACER;
            
            gridButtonInsets = WIN_GRID_BUTTON_INSETS;          
            gridCBOInsets = WIN_GRID_CBO_INSETS;
            gridLabelInsets = WIN_GRID_LABEL_INSETS;
            gridRadioInsets = WIN_GRID_RADIO_INSETS;
            gridSliderInsets = WIN_GRID_SLIDER_INSETS;
        }
        else if (os == OS.MAC_LINUX)
        {
            tinySizeFont = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.PLAIN, MAC_TINY_FONT_SIZE);
            smallSizeFont = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.PLAIN, MAC_SMALL_FONT_SIZE);
            normalSizeFont = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, MAC_NORMAL_FONT_SIZE);
            largeSizeFont = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, MAC_LARGE_FONT_SIZE);
            bigLabelFont = new Font(Font.SERIF, Font.BOLD, MAC_BIG_LABEL_FONT_SIZE);
            cboChoicesFont = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, MAC_CBO_FONT_SIZE);
            buttonFont = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, MAC_NORMAL_FONT_SIZE);
            preferenceButtonSpacer = MAC_PREFERENCE_BUTTON_SPACER;
            
            gridButtonInsets = MAC_GRID_BUTTON_INSETS;          
            gridCBOInsets = MAC_GRID_CBO_INSETS;
            gridLabelInsets = MAC_GRID_LABEL_INSETS;
            gridRadioInsets = MAC_GRID_RADIO_INSETS;
            gridSliderInsets = MAC_GRID_SLIDER_INSETS;
        }    
    }
}
```